# How to compare two list<t> objects?

Tags: java, list, generics, comparison

I have two lists namely,

`List<Employee> oldEmplist` and `List<Employee> newEmplist` and i have to compare both the list with only 2 properties of employee class namely `empOrigId`,`empOrigNumber`and these two properties will be set only for `newEmplist` so i have to compare these properties from `newEmpList` with `empId`,`empNumber` in `oldEmpList`. If this matches i have to replace the whole element in the `oldEmpList` with the matching item in the `newEmplist`.

Any suggestion how this can be done?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075656/simple-way-to-find-if-two-different-lists-contain-exactly-the-same-elements - although most approaches rely on the `equals` being defined on the objects as appropriate. If you need to do something "extra" in the operation - then get to writing code (e.g. a loop, perhaps with two iterators, and building an appropriate result). It is Java [7], after all.

Answer (score 4):

```
ListIterator<Employee> iterator = oldEmplist.listIterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Employee x = iterator.next();
    for (Employee y : newEmplist) {
        if (x.empOrigId == y.empId && x.empOrigNumber == y.empNumber) {
            iterator.set(y);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My understanding of the question is that this would be correct if the line that says `break;` were not there.