# Java Is one arraylist part of another in order

Tags: java, android, arraylist, contains

I am making an app for android. I am trying to guess what song the user just played on xylophone. I have: `private List<String> mDespacito = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("f", "a","d","d"));` and `private List<String> mPlayed = new ArrayList<String>();` When user presses one key on the xylophone, I add the key he pressed to the mPlayed arraylist, like this:

```
public void playD(View v){
    Log.d("Xylophone", "Played D!");
  mSoundPool.play(mDSoundId,LEFT_VOLUME,RIGHT_VOLUME,PRIORITY,NO_LOOP,NORMAL_PLAY_RATE);
    mPlayed.add("d");
    CheckForSong();
```

}

Now, CheckForSong contains:

```
public void CheckForSong(){
    if (mPlayed.containsAll(mDespacito)){
        Log.d("Xylophone","You just played despacito");
        mPlayed.removeAll(mDespacito);
    }
}
```

So, it should do:

```
played F
played A
played D
played D
You just played despacito
```

But it does:

```
played F
played A
played D
You just played despacito
played D
```

And you can do even:

```
played F
played G
played A
played G
played D
You just played despacito
```

And I know why: Because of `if (mPlayed.containsAll(mDespacito))` just checks if elements of mDespacito are in mPlayed. But i need to check if there are all elements of mDespacito (Including those which are there twice) and if they are in the right order. Is there any command like that I can use? Thanks

Comment: `Collections.indexOfSubList` might help you!

Comment: If you treated individual notes as characters which would get concatenated into a string, you could use `String.contains()` which takes the order into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Collections.indexOfSubList` is the answer. I use it like this:

```
public void CheckForSong(){
    int contains = Collections.indexOfSubList(mPlayed, mDespacito);
    if (contains != -1){
        Log.d("Xylophone","You just played despacito");
        mPlayed.removeAll(mDespacito);
    }
}
```

more about `Collections.indexOfSubList`:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/collections_indexofsublist.htm

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
mPlayed.equals(mDespacito);
```

instead, so the elements will be checked in order and elements.

IMPORTANT: If you are not using Strings as your code demonstrate, you need to implement hashCode and equals in the class that you add to the list.

The following snippet results in displaying true twice then false

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList();
        a.add("f");
        a.add("a");
        a.add("d");
        a.add("d");

        ArrayList<String> b = new ArrayList();
        b.add("f");
        b.add("a");
        b.add("d");
        b.add("d");

        System.out.println(a.equals(b));
        System.out.println(b.equals(a));
        b.add("c");
        System.out.println(a.equals(b));
    }
}
```

Else: You can compare the list yourself:

```
 public boolean equals(List f, List s) {
      if(f.size() != s.size())
         return false;
      for(int i = 0; i < f.size(); i++)
          if(!f.get(i).equals(s.get(i))
             return false;
 }
```

But remember the tip that if you are not using primitives or String you need to implement hashCode and equals on your objects.

Comment: hmm, no that does not work, too. This time it does not even show You just played despacito. I think it is because of mPlayed does not equal mDespacito, it just contains mDespacito

Answer (score 0):

`list1.equals(list2)` can be used

A very nice explanation is given in the below link. Please find.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1075699/4994582

Comment: hmm, no that does not work, too. This time it does not even show You just played despacito. I think it is because of mPlayed does not equal mDespacito, it just contains mDespacito