# assertj / Java comparing objects with list field ignoring order of elements in list

Tags: java, assertj

I am looking to compare 2 list of objects (say Foo) in test.

```
List<Foo> fooA;
List<Foo> fooB;
```

Each Foo entry has one of the fields of type List (say Bar)

```
class Foo {
  private List<Bar> bars;
  ....
}

assertThat(fooA).isEqualTo(fooB);
```

Comparison fails because elements of bars are same but in different order.

Is there a way to compare them ignoring order?

I am not looking for below option.

```
assertThat(fooA).usingElementComparatorIgnoringFields("bars").isEqualTo(fooB);
```

Ideally I would like to compare all the fields

Comment: The comparison would fail even if the items were in the same order because the 2 lists are 2 different objects.

Comment: See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1075699/6383857)

Comment: Silly question:  does `Foo` has an `equals` method defined?

Comment: Foo has an equals method defined and it checks if 2 list fields are equal. I tried updating it to check for containsAll instead but that din't help.

Comment: for groovy, use @EqualsAndHashCode. for java override equals/hashcode

Answer (score 13):

you can do this with assertJ:

```
assertThat(fooA).usingRecursiveComparison().ignoringCollectionOrder().isEqualTo(fooB)
```

Comment: Recursive comparison allows you to compare field by field recursively even if they were not of the same type.

Comment: This answer save my day on `containsExactlyInAnyOrderElementsOf` having list entry with `OffsetDateTime` with different offset issue that could be fixed with 
`.usingRecursiveComparison().ignoringCollectionOrder().withComparatorForType(Comparator.comparing(a -> a.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)),OffsetDateTime.class).isEqualTo(List.of(...`

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is [`containsExactlyInAnyOrderElementsOf(Iterable)`](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#containsExactlyInAnyOrderElementsOf(java.lang.Iterable)) defined in `IterableAssert`  (emphasis is mine) :

> Verifies that the actual group contains exactly **the given values** and
>   nothing else, **in any order**.

You could write so :

```
List<Foo> fooA;
List<Foo> fooB;
//...
assertThat(fooA).containsExactlyInAnyOrderElementsOf(fooB);
```

Comment: The question about comparing objects containing lists, not about comparing the lists themselves