# How to compare variables to another disordered variables?

Tags: java

I want to do a program in Java to compare 2 triangles. It doesn't matter the order of the angles to compare it, and I know that I could do it with `if` statements, but is any other more efficient way to compare the 3 angles to another 3 angles, as it doesn't matter that the triangle is rotated, because is exactly the same? (in Java)

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: I just want to know if 2 triangles are equals. Even if they introduce for example: 90º 30º 30º and the other triangle 30º 30º 90º. As they are exactly the same triangle just rotated. But i dont want to use ifs as I will have to use a big amount of them

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

- Put the angles for each triangle in a separate [List](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html).
- Sort the two lists.
- Check whether the two lists are [equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075656/simple-way-to-find-if-two-different-lists-contain-exactly-the-same-elements).

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Double> first = new ArrayList<>(List.of(90.0, 30.0, 30.0));
        List<Double> second = new ArrayList(List.of(30.0, 30.0, 90.0));
        Collections.sort(first);
        Collections.sort(second);
        System.out.println(first.equals(second));
    }
}
```